# Django: displaying foreign key model in parent model's detail view template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, foreign-keys

I have the following two models:

```
class SpecimenImage(models.Model):
   image = ImageField(upload_to='images/')
   usi_image = models.ForeignKey('SpecimenRecord', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Unique Specimen Identifier')
   ...

class SpecimenRecord(models.Model):
   usi = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20, verbose_name='Unique Specimen Identifier')
   species = models.ForeignKey(Species, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
   locality = models.ForeignKey(Locality, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
   date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
   collector = models.ManyToManyField(Collector, verbose_name='Collector(s)', null=True, blank=True)
   ...
```

I have a generic detail view for `SpecimenRecord`:

```
...
class SpecimenDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = SpecimenRecord
```

Here is the urls.py:

```
...
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('specimen/<str:pk>', views.SpecimenDetailView.as_view(), name='specimen-detail'),
    ]
```

My question is, how do I display and loop through all of the `SpecimenImage` instances associated with a single `SpecimenRecord` object in the html template? I can easily display the information for each `SpecimenRecord` by using `{{ specimenrecord.usi }}`, etc., but I cannot figure out how to display each image.

I've tried using the information on the MDN website for generic detail views (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views):

```
{% for copy in book.bookinstance_set.all %}
  <!-- code to iterate across each copy/instance of a book -->
{% endfor %}
```

Here is the code I tried in my template `specimenrecord_detail.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load thumbnail %}

{% block content %}
...
  {% for copy in specimenrecord.specimenimage_set.all %}
    <div class="gallery">
      <img src="{% thumbnail copy.image '1920' as im %}{{ im.url }}{% endthumbnail %}" alt="specimen image"
        srcset="
          {% thumbnail copy.image '544' as im %}  {{ im.url }} {{ im.x }}w{% endthumbnail %},
          {% thumbnail copy.image '768' as im %}  {{ im.url }} {{ im.x }}w{% endthumbnail %},
          {% thumbnail copy.image '992' as im %}  {{ im.url }} {{ im.x }}w{% endthumbnail %},
          {% thumbnail copy.image '1200' as im %}  {{ im.url }} {{ im.x }}w{% endthumbnail %},
          {% thumbnail copy.image '1920' as im %}  {{ im.url }} {{ im.x }}w{% endthumbnail %}"
        alt="specimen image"
        sizes="100vw"
      />
    </div>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

However, this code yielded an empty `<div>`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is the correct code, assuming your models are exactly as you have shown and you didn't set a `related_name` on the ForeignKey. Are you sure that specimenrecord has images associated with it?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, I uploaded two images to test out my models. I have another html template for specimenimages that is just a generic list view, and they show up fine there. So I'm not sure what else I could be missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with the code, I found a solution. By wrapping the code below around the `<img src>`, the images appear in the div:

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{ copy.image.url }}">
  <img src=.....>
</a>
```

(I'm not sure why this works, but I'm glad I got the result I wanted.)